# glibc linking causes smaller binary which is broken

Tags: gcc, makefile, cmake, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to compile a program on Ubuntu 16.04 (e.g. zbackup) into a single fat binary that can run on BusyBox Linux. Using a customised CMAKE script I am linking with the following options which seems to make the binary grow to 4MB+. This is okay, it seems things are being shoved into the binary.

```
  -lcrypto
  -lz
  -ldl
  -static-libstdc++
  -static-libgcc
```

Next I try adding the `-static` flag so that I can include the final piece which is missing however when I add the `-static` option and then build again the binary is actually smaller at approx 2MB+ and it is broken. When I try to run the binary it simply says `file or folder not found`

I just can't seem to pin down why the `-static` option is causing the output binary to be broken.

Comment: In your build, did you get warning like, "warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking"?

Comment: do an `objdump -t` of the binary with the -static, and one on the binary without, and do a diff.   It sounds like the -static is causing the libstdc++ and libgcc to not be linked in.

Comment: @eric when running the working binary (without -static) on the target busybox it give the error `/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found` but just does file or folder not found for the broken binary (with -static). CMAKE does not show any error output when compiling though.

@user2766918 the output from objdump is huge for both files. Not sure where to start in the mountain of text that diff shows (about 10 pages worth)

Answer (score 1):

From the gcc man page:

> -static On systems that support dynamic linking, this prevents linking with the shared libraries. On other systems, this option has no
>   effect.

Thus, it's preventing linking to some shared libraries, which is what is breaking you, and likely what's making it smaller.   Likely it is not linking to the crypto library, etc.   Again, use `objdump -t` before and after, and figure out which symbols are disappearing.